# Release Installer Object after using comtypes.client.CreateObject()

Tags: python, comtypes

I wrote a function in python using the `comtypes.client` module, the function should supposedly open the database from a .msi file and write a special (key, value) pair. My issue so far is once the function is called with no problems, I try to use `os.rename()` to rename the .msi file afterwards and get a permission error:

`PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

what I understand is that my COM object is still in use and so I cannot access the file, The function and function calls look like (obviously this is very simplified but should look work as such):

```
import comtypes.client
import os, shutil

def setInstallerAttribute(installer_path, attribute_key, attribute_value):
    installerCOM = comtypes.client.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
    installerDatabase = installerCOM.OpenDatabase (installer_path, 1)
    view = installerDatabase.OpenView ("INSERT INTO Property (Property, Value) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')".format(attribute_key, attribute_value))
    view.Execute
    installerDatabase.Commit
    view = None
    installerDatabase = None
    installerCOM = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = '{}'.format(msi_fullapth)
    key = "Build"
    value = "test_value"
    if os.path.exists(input):
        setInstallerAttribute(input, key, value)
        os.rename(input, {some other path})
```

The function is written because previously I was using a VBScript to set this (key, value) pair:

```
Option Explicit

Dim installer, database, view, myproperty, stdout, key

Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set database = installer.OpenDatabase (WScript.Arguments.Item(0), 1)

' Update Property'
'Set view = database.OpenView ("UPDATE Property SET Value = '" & myproperty & "' WHERE Property = 'MYPROPERTY'")'

myproperty = WScript.Arguments.Item(2)
key = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)

' Add/Insert Property'
Set view = database.OpenView ("INSERT INTO Property (Property, Value) VALUES ('" & key & "', '" & myproperty & "')")

view.Execute
database.Commit

Set database = Nothing
Set installer = Nothing
Set view = Nothing
```

I would call this in my python code with `os.system(cscript {VBScript} {path} {Key} {Value})`, however I want minimal external dependencies as possible with my python code. I was looking around for some answers, I looked into the `comtypes` documentation to see if I can explicitly release or "uncouple" my COM object. I tried using `installerCOM.Quit()` and `installerCOM.Exit()` which seem not be options for `WindowsInstaller.Installer` Objects.

Finally, I read in several previous non-python (C# mainly) answers on StackOverflow stating that setting the COM object variables to `null` would solve this, this is also clear from the VBScript but this does not seem to work in python with `None`

Comment: You can try to force a garbage collect on you variable: `del installerDatabase` and `del installerCOM` but I doubt it will be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```py
import gc
def setInstallerAttribute(installer_path, attribute_key, attribute_value):
    installerCOM = comtypes.client.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
    installerDatabase = installerCOM.OpenDatabase (installer_path, 1)
    view = installerDatabase.OpenView ("INSERT INTO Property (Property, Value) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')".format(attribute_key, attribute_value))
    view.Execute
    installerDatabase.Commit
    del view
    del installerDatabase
    del installerCOM
    gc.collect()
```

Comment: Yes this seems to fix the issue, thank you. I can award the bounty in 21 hours.

Comment: One more question, if I use for example `record = view.Fetch`, how I can output `record ` in any meaningful way for debugging?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know more than that about COM objects. Perhaps start a new question on SO.